# Sql insert multiple rows if not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a sql table that has two columns id and name. I have list of names about 20 and I need to write a query that checks if name exists before insert.

Is there a better way of doing this rather then just having  the below query 20 times but with different names (I need do this in t-sql):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT* 
              FROM   mytable 
              WHERE  name = 'Dan') 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO mytable 
                  (name) 
      VALUES     ('dan') 
  END
```

Comment: Where is the list of names you want to exclude, stored?

Comment: Just on an email at the minute. It needs to be tsql I can't use the import tool

Comment: Can you use the name as a parameter?

Comment: Ye can do, how do I get it to check a list of names?

Comment: You could try `INSERT INTO mytable ... WHERE Name NOT IN ('<Name1>', '<Name2>', '<Name3>'...)`

Answer (score 27):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
SELECT  NewNames.Name
FROM    ( VALUES ('Name1'), ('Name2'), ('Name3') ) AS NewNames (Name)
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   MyTable AS MT
                     WHERE  MT.Name = NewNames.Name );
```

Comment: Is there a limit on how many values you can have in the ``from`` clause?  Can it be in the millions?

Answer (score 9):

I think you could use a merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO myTable AS Target
USING (VALUES ('name1'),('name2'),('...')) AS source (NAME)
ON Target.NAME = Source.NAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (NAME) VALUES (name)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can filter values with `NOT EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO myTable (
    Name
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    Name
FROM (
        VALUES ('Name 1'),
               ('Name 2')
    ) AS NewNames(Name)
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TargetTable WHERE myTable.Name = NewNames.Name)
```

If your new names are in another table, you can change the select query in the above one.

Please note, that the `DISTINCT` keyword is necessary to filter out the duplications in the source data.

Comment: It worked for me! 
If anyone is trying to do same for tables with multiple columns, you can do as:
INSERT INTO myTable (
    name, code
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    name, code
FROM (
        VALUES ('Name 1','Code 1'),
               ('Name 2','Code2')
    ) AS NewNames(name, code)
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable m WHERE m.name = NewNames.name)

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using `insert`:

```
with names as (
      select 'Dan' as name union all
      select 'name2' union all
      . . .
     )
insert into myTable(name)
    select distinct name
    from myTable
    where not exists (select 1 from mytable t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Note:  you may want to create a unique index on `mytable(name)` so the database does the checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
SELECT Name FROM
(
    VALUES ('Name 1'),
           ('Name 2')
) AS Names(Name)
WHERE Name NOT IN
(
    SELECT Name FROM MyTable
)
```

Answer (score 1):

untested so there might be some minor errors:

```
merge into mytable x
using (
    values ('name1')
         , ('name2')
         , ...
         , ('namen')
) as y (name)
    on x.name = y.name
when not matched then 
    insert (name)
    values (y.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT IGNORE INTO myTable (column1, column2) VALUES (val1, val2),(val3,val4),(val5,val6);`

INSERT IGNORE will allow skip on duplicate values

Comment: IGNORE doesn't exist in SQL SERVER. 
Similar functionality being: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21220868/1918179