# How does Spark handle failure scenarios involving JDBC data source?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I’m writing a data source that shares similarities with Spark’s JDBC data source implementation, and I’d like to ask how Spark handles certain failure scenarios. To my understanding, if an executor dies while it’s running a task, Spark will revive the executor and try to re-run that task. However, how does this play out in the context of data integrity and Spark’s JDBC data source API (e.g. `df.write.format("jdbc").option(...).save()`)?

In the savePartition function of [JdbcUtils.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala), we see Spark calling the commit and rollback functions of the Java connection object generated from the database url/credentials provided by the user (see below). But if an executor dies right after commit() finishes or before rollback() is called, does Spark try to re-run the task and write the same data partition again, essentially creating duplicate committed rows in the database? And what happens if the executor dies in the middle of calling commit() or rollback()?

```
try {
    ...
    if (supportsTransactions) {
        conn.commit()
    }
    committed = true
    Iterator.empty
} catch {
    case e: SQLException =>
        ...
        throw e
} finally {
    if (!committed) {
        // The stage must fail.  We got here through an exception path, so
        // let the exception through unless rollback() or close() want to
        // tell the user about another problem.
        if (supportsTransactions) {
          conn.rollback()
        }
        conn.close()
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to introduce some de-duplication logic exactly for the reasons described. You might end up with the same committed twice (or more) indeed.

Comment: Could you please describe how you implemented this de-duplication logic? I'm curious about details like where you added it and what type of database you were working with.

Comment: It was an Amazon RedShift and I had to add additional timestamping columns later used for de-dup in the ETL process. Generally speaking you just need some unique key to be able to tell if it's a new record or a duplicate, obviously RedShift is not very good with keys hence timestamps. What's your data target?

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to work with SQL Server. I don't know much about Redshift, but I'll investigate to see if I can implement a similar strategy.

Comment: With SQL Server it's actually simpler - have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21220868/5478299.

Answer (score 3):

> But if an executor dies right after commit() finishes or before rollback() is called, does Spark try to re-run the task and write the same data partition again, essentially creating duplicate committed rows in the database?

What would you expect since Spark SQL (which is a high-level API over RDD API) does not really know much about all the peculiarities of JDBC or any other protocol? Not to mention the underlying execution runtime, i.e. the Spark Core.

When you write a structured query like `df.write.format(“jdbc”).option(...).save()` Spark SQL translates it to a distributed computation using the low-level assembly-like RDD API. Since it tries to embrace as many "protocols" as possible (incl. JDBC), Spark SQL's DataSource API leaves much of the error handling to the data source itself.

The core of Spark that schedules tasks (that does not know or even care what the tasks do) simply watches execution and if a task fails, it will attempt to execute it again (until 3 failed attempts by default).

So when you write a custom data source, you know the drill and have to deal with such retries in your code.

One way to handle errors is to register a task listener using [TaskContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.TaskContext) (e.g. `addTaskCompletionListener` or `addTaskFailureListener`).